# How do I call a sed command in a python script?

Tags: scripts, python, sed

Through python script, I am trying to replace a string by a string in a file using `sed` command. I do that through `subprocess.call` as it in the script.

When I run the command in the shell script or command, it runs fine, but in python I get a result saying "No input file".
Any idea how to fix that error?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sed -i -e 's/hello/helloworld/g'","www.txt"], shell=True)
```

Output

```
No input file
```

Comment: Next time, ask generic programming questions on [so].

Comment: Why use sed anyway in  a python script?  python has built-in tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid `subprocess` and implement the functionality of `sed` with Python instead, e.g. with the `fileinput` module:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("www.txt", inplace=True):
    # inside this loop the STDOUT will be redirected to the file
    # the comma after each print statement is needed to avoid double line breaks
    print line.replace("hello", "helloworld"),
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it messes up the file, it gives spaces between the lines everytime i do replace !. any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: It shouldn't do that unless you omitted the comma in the end of the print statement. Do you have that in the script? Check it again.

Comment: Won't this be _significantly_ slower than using `sed`?

Comment: Hi I have been trying this but its obviously been written for Python 2.X however when I put parentheses around the arguments to the print command on the last line it seems to work but inserts a blank line between every line of the file to be edited. How would this be modified to cope with Python 3.

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone `print(line.replace("hello", "helloworld"), end="")` should do it. The trailing comma at the end of the Python 2 print statement suppressed the line break, which is what the keyword parameter `end=""` does in Python 3.

Comment: Aah great that works. I was just in the process of munging some text locally to see if I could make it work for Python3 but you've saved me the trouble. Thanks :) +1 from me..

Answer (score 18):

With [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), either every argument to the command should be a separate item in the list (and `shell` should not be set to `True`):

```
subprocess.call(["sed", "-i", "-e",  's/hello/helloworld/g', "www.txt"])
```

Or, the entire command should one string, with `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call(["sed -i -e 's/hello/helloworld/g' www.txt"], shell=True)
```

The arguments are treated similarly for `subprocess.call` and `Popen`, and as the documentation for [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) says:

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. …
>   If `args` is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string,
>   and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to
>   the shell itself. That is to say, `Popen` does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

Comment: how do you do the same if you wanted to pass variables instead of values to the sed?